# Is it possible to avoid login redirection to Godaddy Office 365?

Tags: oauth, office365, shared-hosting

Anyone knows disable or turn off login redirection when using Godaddy Office365?

Our system using Popup window for Office365 Oauth Authentication process, Godaddy makes url redirection (microsoft -> Godaddy) so, winwow.parent value lost because redirection.

Is it possible?